# Git to Mercurial conversion fails because of bad file

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, blob, git-fsck

I'm trying to convert a git repository to mercurial. Partway through it fails with the following error:

```
$ hg convert --datesort git-repo hg-repo
initializing destination hg-repo repository
scanning source...
sorting...
converting...
77 Some commit
76 Some other commit
fatal: git cat-file 1bd9dc57043a032dc05dbd8eabff457e560cd70a: bad file
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: cannot read 'blob' object at 1bd9dc57043a032dc05dbd8eabff457e560cd70a
```

Running `git fsck` within the git repo does not reveal any errors.

How can I figure out where the problem is, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What do you see if you do a git diff for `1bd9d...`? Is there a binary file that was updated?

Comment: The diff for the revision that corresponds to 76 doesn't show anything weird. There are a number of binary files that were added at that time. Checking out the revision and running a `git fsck` doesn't show any errors